# Pinescript question, sell 50% at profit and let 50% run

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am trying to have 2 sell orders but I want to have a profit and stop as well based on pips not price. If I use `strategy.exit` it would look like this for my stop and profit but I can't figure out how to split the sells.

```
strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop = 100, profit = 100)
```

---

Is this possible? I know my coding isnt very good any help is greatly appreciated.

```
shortCondition = close < lowerBand and close[1] > lowerBand

if (shortCondition)

strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, qty=pos_size)

strategy.order("short1", strategy.long, qty=size_trim, comment="closefirst50%")

strategy.order("short2", strategy.long, qty=size_trim, comment="closesecond50%")


longCondition = close > upperBand and close[1] < upperBand

if (longCondition)

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, qty=pos_size)

strategy.order("long1", strategy.short, qty=size_trim, comment="closefirst50%")

strategy.order("long2", strategy.short, qty=size_trim, comment="closesecond50%")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use 2 strategy.exit indeed

```
if (shortCondition)
    
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, qty=pos_size)
    
if strategy.position_size < 0

    strategy.exit("exit short TP", qty=size_trim, profit = 100, comment="closefirst50%")
    
    strategy.exit("exit short SL", loss = 100, comment="close the remaining 50%")
```

Comment: What can I do if I want to move my stop to the first take profit if it gets there and let the second 50% run to 200?